# Wordpress Audio Tag not working on Custom Field

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom field and I want to add an audio file to it. I tried using Wordpress' audio tag `[audio mp3=""][/audio]` but it just displays it as regular text. It works fine if I add an iframe to the custom field but the audio tag doesn't work. Any help? Thanks.

```
       <div class="post">
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></a></h2>
            <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Audio', true); ?>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add do_shortcode() for the shortcode to render.  ex:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Audio', true)); ?>
```

Comment: Would that interfere with other posts where I added an iframe to the custom field (instead of the audio shortcode)?.